# Error in Sensobol function, object 'Y_A' not found

Tags: r

I try to calculating sobol index using Sensobol package in R.
So I make a sobol matrix using:

```
input.df <- sobol_matricies(N=50, params = c('x1','x2','x3','x4','x5')).
```

And then I calculate 'y' with this matrix.

```
y <- output.df$MY
```

And then try to calculating sobol index as follow:

```
MY.sobol <- sobol_indices(matrices = input.df, Y = y, N = 50, params = c('x1','x2','x3','x4','x5'))
```

But R studio returned error as follow:
Error in sobol_boot(d = d, N = N, params = params, first = first, total = total,  :
object 'Y_A' not found

I am wondering what is causing this error.

Thank you.

Comment: Pay attention to code : `sobol_matrices` and not `sobol_matricies`. Additionally we do not know what is `output.df` so we can't reproduce your issue

Comment: I found error in "MY.sobol <- ". I modified it "MY.sobl <- sobol_indices(Y=y, N=50, params = c('x1','x2','x3','x4','x5')". Thank you for your comment, Basti.